# Google App Script Card Service datepicker returns strange value

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple script that creates and a Gmail Add on. Using Card Service the user can enter values that once submitted send the values to a Google Sheet. Everything works fine accept the date field which returns values such as {msSinceEpoch=1.6145568E12}. Attempts to use Utilities.formatDate fails to rectify this the default value of '1/1/1970' is returned. It is not clear to me why this is the case?

The Card Service includes the following for the date field:

```
section.addWidget(CardService.newDatePicker().setValueInMsSinceEpoch(Date.now())
.setFieldName('fieldD')
.setTitle(date));
```

This is followed by a standard action:

```
var action = CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName('enterAction');
```

And a function which inserts the values in the Google Sheet:

```
function enterAction(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID").getActiveSheet();
....
var inputValues5 = e.formInput['fieldD'];
...
var values = [.....[inputValues5],...];
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,7).setValues([values]);
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

can you try it like this?

```
section.addWidget(CardService.newDatePicker().setValueInMsSinceEpoch(new Date())
.setFieldName('fieldD')
.setTitle(date));
```

or

```
let newDate = new Date();
section.addWidget(CardService.newDatePicker().setValueInMsSinceEpoch(newDate)
            .setFieldName('fieldD')
            .setTitle(date));
```

Also not sure about the .setValueInMsSinceEpoch(), is there another function you can call?

Comment: The description in the documentation for `setValueInMsSinceEpoch()` really sucks one says is supposed to be a string the other says it's supposed to be a number and both say is supposed to be the number of milliseconds. But neither say that it's supposed to be a Date() object  [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/date-time-picker#setValueInMsSinceEpoch(String))

Answer (score 0):

1.6145568E12 is March 1st 2021 in milliseconds since the epoch (this is the expected format). I don't see your code for the formatDate statement, but something like this should work:

```
var fieldD = e.formInput['fieldD'];
var inputDate = new Date(fieldD.meetingTime.msSinceEpoch);
var inputValues5 = Utilities.formatDate(inputDate, 
                                        e.userTimezone.id, 
                                        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```